# Codeigniter Menu Based on Access Level

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter

I am trying to find a way to create a menu in Codeigniter that displays different options based on the access level of the user i.e. If they're an admin, and editor or just a normal user. Some of their options will overlap.

I've considered adding an if statement to the view, but this isn't very good MVC. I've also considered creating a multi-dimensional array within a controller that sets the menu options based on the user access level.

I'd really appreciate ideas and opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your user accounts should have a set of roles, i.e. Dashboard, Sales, Payments, Products, Product Add/Edit, Product Delete, Reports, etc. (you can use Ion Auth's groups as roles). Then you create a view which will display the menu and you will pass the logged user roles to that view. Then you go through all roles and compare them to the user roles. If the user has a role to see a specific page then you add a link to that page in the menu.

That's it :-)
Hope I helped.

Comment: So you would put a small if statement within the view to display specific menus based on user roles? I think this is probably what I'll do, but wasn't sure whether it was considered 'correct' MVC.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry if didn't explained it right. And about the correct MVC... I don't know if that's the best way to do it but it's simple enough and it'll work :) and I'm about to implement it in an upcoming project. Hope it'll help to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I always make this one harder than it should be.  Why not just have separate views (partials) for each user level?  I.e.:

```
<?php
if ($this->user_model->isAdmin())
{
    $this->load->view('user_menu_admin');
}
elseif ($this->user_model->isModerator())
{
    $this->load->view('user_menu_moderator');
}
elseif ($this->user_model->isMember())
{
    $this->load->view('user_menu_member');
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('user_menu_guest');
}
```

Comment: I was using this method originally, but I found that I was duplicating a lot of functionality that was needed in more than one role type.